# Would method definition count as a statement or expression in Java?

Tags: java, expression

I understand a method definition is made of expressions and statements, but would the whole method definition itself count as a statement or expression? What about parts of method such as method header or method definition, would they be an expression or statement respectively?

For clarification, the method header comprises the access modifiers, return type, method name, and parameters; if this method threw any exceptions, they would appear next.

The method body is a block that contains the code of what the method will do.

Both of these make up a method definition all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method definition, or formally a [method declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4), is neither an [expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) nor a [statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement). You cannot use a method declaration inside a block like statements and it does not have a "value" required for being an expression. A method declaration is part/subset of a [class member declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6) (which are also no statements or expressions).

Comment: The method header would not be an expression nor statement as well?

Comment: @rickyrob Check the definition of "expressions" and "statements", method headers are not part of them.